# Phishing and emails from icloud.com

Tags: email, phishing

Recently, various companies have been sending me emails from addresses like
support_at_example_com_r1a8nd4o6m7@icloud.com.

I used to be able to determine if an email was not a phishing email by looking at the domain, but that method is not available when the domain is icloud.com.

Is there any way to know which company sent me the email from icloud.com?

**2022/1/2**

This seems to be a conversion by Apple's Hyde My Email feature.

Comment: Why do you think a company sent the email?

Comment: @schroeder In some cases, the same kind of mail that used to be sent from example.com is now being sent from icloud.com instead, so I guess they changed the address. In other cases, I get emails related to my actions (create account, logged in, purchase, etc...).

Comment: So, there's no phishing? You just want to know in case there is phishing? Then it's simple; you contact the company and get them to confirm the address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no. Just as you can't determine anyone's identity behind an email address.

Long answer: if there is enough correlating public data that would allow you to connect this address to a person or company, then you can create a connection. If not, then you can't.

Report the email to your email provider and cloud. They know who it is.